# Websockets Client not printing message -- Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, python-sockets

The Connection is being established but no message is being printed to the terminal.
Here is my code.

```
import websocket, json

cc = 'btcusd'

interval = '1m'

socket = f'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/{cc}@kline_{interval}'

print('This part of the code has been executed')


def on_open(ws):
  print("Opened")

def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)

def on_close(ws):
    print("Connection Closed")

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(socket, on_open=on_open, on_message=on_message, on_close=on_close)
ws.run_forever()
```

Comment: do you have link to documentation? Show it in question (not in comment)

Comment: base on documentation on https://docs.binance.org/api-reference/dex-api/ws-streams.html and https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/web-socket-streams.md it seems you have to `subscribe` after `opened`

Comment: maybe you should use module like https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ or you should check in source code how it works.

Comment: code works for me for `cc = 'bnbbtc'` or `cc = 'btcusdt'` (with `t` at the end)  but not for `cc = 'btcusd'`